# check if the Linux kernel my PC runs has been maliciously modified

Tags: debian, apt, linux-kernel, hashsum

```
$ uname -a
Linux mypcname 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2 (2016-04-08) i686 GNU/Linux
```

I want to check that this ^^ Linux kernel on my PC has not been maliciously tampered with. I have no reason to suspect that it has been, but I would like to check anyway. My thinking is that comparing my kernel software with the same version that has been made publicly available by the original developers of the software should constitute a "good enough" check for my purposes. If you see any glaring errors in this way of thinking then please let me know. I know other malicious programs besides the kernel can run on a computer, but for the purposes of this question I am just interested in the kernel.

Please note that the checks need not be done by the kernel as it runs. There is nothing preventing me from turning off my PC and booting another kernel or OS, or even taking out the hard drive and plugging it into another PC to run the checks on. But really I just want to do a quick check, so I will probably just do all checks using the existing kernel. Perfect? No. Good enough for my purposes? Certainly.

I get the hashes of the kernel like so:

```
$ apt-cache show linux-image-3.16.0-4-686-pae
Package: linux-image-3.16.0-4-686-pae
Source: linux
Version: 3.16.7-ckt25-2
Installed-Size: 118358
Maintainer: Debian Kernel Team <debian-kernel@lists.debian.org>
Architecture: i386
Provides: linux-modules-3.16.0-4-686-pae
Depends: kmod | module-init-tools, linux-base (>= 3~), debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, initramfs-tools (>= 0.110~) | linux-initramfs-tool
Pre-Depends: debconf | debconf-2.0
Recommends: firmware-linux-free (>= 3~), irqbalance, libc6-i686
Suggests: linux-doc-3.16, debian-kernel-handbook, grub-pc | extlinux
Breaks: at (<< 3.1.12-1+squeeze1), initramfs-tools (<< 0.110~)
Description-en: Linux 3.16 for modern PCs
 The Linux kernel 3.16 and modules for use on PCs with one or more
 processors supporting PAE.
 .
 This kernel requires PAE (Physical Address Extension). This feature is
 supported by the Intel Pentium Pro/II/III/4/4M/D, Xeon, Core and Atom; AMD
 Geode NX, Athlon (K7), Duron, Opteron, Sempron, Turion or Phenom;
 Transmeta Efficeon; VIA C7; and some other processors.
 .
 This kernel also runs on a Xen hypervisor.  It supports both privileged
 (dom0) and unprivileged (domU) operation.
Description-md5: b2c3f405aab9f0fe07863b318891f277
Homepage: https://www.kernel.org/
Section: kernel
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-3.16.0-4-686-pae_3.16.7-ckt25-2_i386.deb
Size: 33408936
MD5sum: ce730b36742b837e3990889f2d897b60
SHA1: 6f0816a4f4a2a24e7b74e9fa903dde778d825e63
SHA256: 63a59e3a09afa720ce1c9b71bb33176e943e59aa90a9e3d92100b1d3b98cd1c6
```

So I have a few questions:

1. Are these the hashes for the `pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-3.16.0-4-686-pae_3.16.7-ckt25-2_i386.deb` file?
2. Where can I find these hashes online to see if mine are correct?
3. Assuming the answer to (1) is 'yes', then how can I check that the kernel that is actually running on my pc is the same as would be installed by this `.deb` file?

**I have faced opposition to this question in the comments...**

I didn't post this question looking for a debate. The checks I ask for in this question are not intended to be a panacea (there is no such thing when it comes to computer security). If you have a problem with this question then please consider that the developers of the Linux kernel itself sign their software with PGP keys and have suggested:

> All kernel releases are cryptographically signed using
>   OpenPGP-compliant signatures. Everyone is strongly encouraged to
>   verify the integrity of downloaded kernel releases by verifying the
>   corresponding signatures.

(source: https://www.kernel.org/signature.html)

I understand that PGP signatures perform a different function to hashing a file to check for modifications, but there are similarities from a security standpoint - especially when it comes to trusting the data output by a compromised system. Hopefully this analogy will prevent readers of this question from dismissing it offhand as this mainly seems to have been the case so far.

Comment: If the kernel you were running had been maliciously tampered with, why would you trust what it let something tell you about whether it had been tampered with?

Comment: There are a number of security packages in debian that will do this sort of thing. But as Michael says if your system is compromised, then you can not trust anything on it. Why just the kernel?

Comment: Authentic is a word that the art world uses, to make you think that the perfectly good reproduction is garbage. It has nothing to do with trust, or malicious tampering.

Comment: I didn't say "prove the kernel is authentic", just "check". I'm after procedures to follow, not a debate.

Comment: For the reason given in the comment, **you can't** "check that the kernel that is actually running on my pc is the same as would be installed by this .deb file", since the malicious kernel could interfere with any such check you ran. It was a hint to [edit] your post so that it might be usefully answerable by including your threat model, or removing the constraints that made it impossible.

Comment: You can check the files contained within package with `dpkg --verify <package-name>`. But as Michael already said, you cannot trust a compromised system.

Comment: @MichaelHomer, debate it is then. When you say, "If the kernel you were running had been maliciously tampered with, why would you trust what it let something tell you about whether it had been tampered with?" - this could just as easily apply to the checks provided on [this page](https://www.kernel.org/signature.html). You will note that _they_ don't provide a threat model on that page either.

Comment: Thankyou for the command @Thomas. And I am well aware I can't trust a compromised system.

Comment: @mulllhausen yeah, but they're also not asking any questions here.

Comment: I'm not interested in a debate. You can edit your question, or not; you're the one who wanted an answer. The kernel.org page isn't trying to verify the running kernel, so I don't see how it's relevant. If you think it is, [edit] your post (not comment) to explain why, and the same for other changes.

Comment: Debian, and most other GNU/Linux, distributions provide no mechanisms to "authenticate" a running Linux kernel.

Comment: Do all the above comments account for the checks being done by removing the hard disk and running the checks from another PC? Note that my question does not rule this out.

Comment: Then it isn't "actually running on \[your\] PC", is it. Your question very much rules that out, *which was why I suggested you might want to edit it*.

Comment: Yes, I'm running it on my PC. I'm not running this kernel software on any other PC. I'm not trying to be difficult here. I would appreciate [not being treated like a fool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_charity).

Comment: @mulllhausen, you need to define for other people what you mean by a "running kernel" and what you mean by "authenticate". Comparing hashes of on-disk binaries does NOT authenticate a kernel.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 I have updated the question. If it still requires clarifications then please be friendly.

Comment: @mulllhausen. Thanks for the clarification.  For your purposes, comparing hashes is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

> Are these the hashes for the pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-3.16.0-4-686-pae_3.16.7-ckt25-2_i386.deb file?

Yes.

> Where can I find these hashes online to see if mine are correct?

[Here!](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/i386/linux-image-3.16.0-4-686-pae/download)

> Assuming the answer to (1) is 'yes', then how can I check that the kernel that is actually running on my pc is the same as would be installed by this .deb file?

I don't know an easy way to do this. `dpkg --verify` is problematic, because it uses the checksums in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/` (easily manipulated), not from the deb file!

You can get the md5sums of the files from the deb file directly

```
dpkg-deb -e linux-image-3.16.0-4-686-pae_3.16.7-ckt25-2_i386.deb
```

This should extract the control files in a directory `DEBIAN` including a file called `md5sums` which contains the md5sums of the files in the package which you can check against your installed versions.

Of course, this is just for educational purposes. I don't know much about security! If you want to have any ***real*** security benefit, you would have to analyze the *whole* system starting with the boot loader while not running...

Comment: Downvoted because your answer clearly does not meet the OPs stated requirement i.e. check that the kernel he is running is authentic.

Comment: @fpmurphy1: It is not clear what is meant. You *can* of course verify your vmlinux.